# pytest collecting 0 items

Tags: python, sockets, pytest

I have a socket program - 2 scripts, server and client. On server side I have many functions. I want to test these functions. I am new to python. Found something called pytest. So for all functions on my server side I did something like this.

```
def fun(a):
   // fn definition
   return b
def test_fun():
   assert fun(test_case) == "expected value"
```

I named this server script as test_server.py and imported pytest. I have imported pytest on client side also and renamed the script to test_client.py Then when I run using

> py.test test_server.py

and then

> py.test test_client.py

On server side it says collecting 0 items, and that's it. It is not collecting any. Any idea where I am going wrong. BTW I tried with simple python codes. There pytest is working properly. Is it that pytest doesn't work with socket programming or am I doing any mistake ? Also there is no mistake in codes without using pytest. It is working perfectly fine when I do

> python test_server.py

and then,

> python test_client.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to test your client functions you should actually mock server responses. If you want to run some integration tests for client. Then start your server with:

```
python test_server.py
```

and run your client tests as:

```
py.test test_client.py
```

py.test only runs functions which names are starting from test_ , so my guess that your server does not even start with pytest.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew that py.test considers functions starting with test_ as test cases but I didn't know that it executes only those functions. Now I may not be able to do as you said because I need to test on server side, not on client side. So, I put the part of server code which takes care of socket connection in a function and named it with test_<some_name> and now its collecting all items.

Comment: I have many functions on server side which I need to test. If a function is defined after it is called, its showing me an error saying its used before assignment. Fine, this is expected. But if I put the function definition before it is used, the server side is just hanging up and showing nothing. I am not able to see where I went wrong. Can someone point me to any material where I can study about how pytest is used with socket programming. At least seeing the execution flow using pytest would help me.